# Puppeteer: how to foreach every button class and click if specific class name found

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

How to foreach every button class and click if specific class name found

```
    <button class="b-deliverytime--slot b-deliverytime--slot-unavailable" aria-label="Not Available Today" title="Not free today">Busy</button>
<button class="b-deliverytime--slot b-deliverytime--slot-available" aria-label="Available Today" title="Today Free">Free</button>
```

I need to find every button with "--slot-available" and click it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use forEach for asynchronous execution as it throws away the promises instead of awaiting them. Use a simple for loop:

```js
const buttons = await page.$$('button[class*="--slot-available"]')

for (const button of buttons)
    await button.click();
```

Comment: and how to select only first matching button in easy way ?

Comment: @Vaikis2006 buttons is an array, so `buttons[0]` is the first one.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a CSS selector to do the filtering:

```
const elements = await page.$$('button[class*="--slot-available"]');

elements.forEach(async element => {
  await element.click();
});
```

The `[attribute*=value]` selector matches every element whose `attribute` value contain a specified `value`.

Comment: tried to log with console.log(element); but nothing is found...